Barcode scanner component doesn't seem to work on community pages, is this right?
I have the below LWC to read a barcode, but it only works in the application, I need it to work on a website (community), but it doesn't seem to work for me.
Has anyone managed to make it work?
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import { getBarcodeScanner } from "lightning/mobileCapabilities";

export default class ScannerBarcode extends LightningElement {
    scannedBarcode = "";
    @api buttonLabel;
    @api buttonColor;
    @api barcodeResult;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.myScanner = getBarcodeScanner();
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--buttonColor", this.buttonColor);
    }

    initBarcodeScanner(event) {
        this.scannedBarcode = "";

        if (this.myScanner != null && this.myScanner.isAvailable()) {
            const scanningOptions = {
                barcodeTypes: [
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.QR,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.CODE_128,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.CODE_93,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.CODE_39,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.DATA_MATRIX,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.EAN_13,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.EAN_8,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.ITF,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.PDF_417,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.UPC_E
                ],
                instructionText: "Scan a Barcode",
                successText: "Scanning complete."
            };
            this.myScanner
                .beginCapture(scanningOptions)
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result);

                    this.barcodeResult = result.value;
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: "Successful Scan",
                            message: "Barcode scanned successfully.",
                            variant: "success"
                        })
                    );
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    if (error.code == "userDismissedScanner") {
                        this.dispatchEvent(
                            new ShowToastEvent({
                                title: "Scanning Cancelled",
                                message: "You cancelled the scanning session.",
                                mode: "sticky"
                            })
                        );
                    } else {
                        this.dispatchEvent(
                            new ShowToastEvent({
                                title: "Barcode Scanner Error",
                                message: "There was a problem scanning the barcode: " + error.message,
                                variant: "error",
                                mode: "sticky"
                            })
                        );
                    }
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    this.myScanner.endCapture();
                });
        } else {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: "Barcode Scanner Is Not Available",
                    message: "Try again from the Salesforce app on a mobile device.",
                    variant: "error"
                })
            );
        }
    }
}


Hi and welcome to SFSE. Could you please [edit] the question to add details around whether you mean in a mobile browser, and which type of digital experience you mean (Aura or LWR)?

yes, an lwc in a mobile browser.
